# how to pass a query variable from server.r to global.r in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
queryvar <- sqlquery(select * from emp)  #in server.r
```

how can I pass this queryvar  to global.r

Comment: you can pass it to global environment as `assign("new.data", queryvar, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can pass it to the global environment with <<-, but that is not good practice.

Comment: i want to use queryvar as a global variable

Comment: @parth in your syntax r u storing data of queryvar in new.data?

Comment: Why not just put the line in global.r instead of server.r?

Comment: @user_033, yes data of queryvar is stored in `new.data`

Comment: @parth thnk u for your answer but it is not working

Comment: you can also just `source` your `server.r` and access the variable(if exists type condition)

Comment: @parth can u share any link on that??

Comment: @user_033, follow [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html), check **Objects visible across all sessions** section